# bash completion causing reboot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

**UPDATE**

set -x seems to produce some useful debugging information. `systemctl` is highly suspect as running `systemctl list-units --full --all` by itself causes the same reboot. Guess I'll be digging into that.

```
set -x
service [TAB]
    ...
    etc/init.d/unattended-upgrades /etc/init.d/unscd /etc/init.d/urandom
    + shopt -u nullglob
    + COMPREPLY+=($( systemctl list-units --full --all 2>/dev/null |                   awk '$1 ~ /\.service$/ { sub("\\.service$", "", $1); print $1 }' ))
    ++ systemctl list-units --full --all
    ++ awk '$1 ~ /\.service$/ { sub("\\.service$", "", $1); print $1 }'

    Broadcast message from root@server
        (/dev/pts/1) at 12:02 ...

    The system is going down for reboot NOW!
    + COMPREPLY=($( compgen -W '${COMPREPLY[@]#${sysvdirs[0]}/}' -- "$cur" ))
    ++ compgen -W '${COMPREPLY[@]#${sysvdirs[0]}/}' -- ''
    + [[ -e /etc/mandrake-release ]]
    Connection to server.mydomain.net closed by remote host.
    Connection to server.mydomain.net closed.
```

I have a virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 with latest patches. when I type `service`+ [TAB] the machine immediately reboots. Other bash completion seems to work fine eg: `ls [TAB]`. Only completion for `service` seems to be problematic. The system logs haven't revealed anything obvious yet. If I uninstall the `bash-completion` package, the problem goes away. Re-installing it, the problem is back.  Any ideas where to look for troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out. An admin replaced the `/bin/systemctl` binary with a shell script which contained the single command `reboot`. I have no idea why someone would do this but since two people have upvoted this question already, I thought I would answer. I don't even think that command is part of 14.04 (Checked a handful of other machines - it's not there) so that's even more bizarre.

The takeaway worth noting here is that `set -x` helped me find the problem.

Comment: You should probably treat this machine as compromised. With something like that done I wouldn't trust it in the slightest.

Comment: @TimBrigham Especially since booby-trapping `systemctl` is the sort of thing an attacker might do to keep you from investigating what *else* had been tampered with...

Comment: Totally agree however I'm not in a position to do much more than document what I fixed and make a recommendation.